# Algebraic maninpulation of formula to isolate a variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to rearrange the following equation to get Rt on its own:

$$ADC = (\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3} - \dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1}) \times 10 \times 1023 $$

With a lot of help I've come up with:

$$(\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3}) = (\dfrac{ADC}{10230} + \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2})$$

$$1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{ADC}{10230} + \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R2}}$$

$$1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$$

$$\dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}-\dfrac{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$$

$$\dfrac{R_3}{R_t}=\dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)-ADC(R_1+R_2)-10230R_2}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$$

$$R_t[10230(R_1 + R_2) - ADC(R_1 + R_2) - 10230R_2] = R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]$$

$$R_t = \dfrac{R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]}{10230(R_1 + R_2) - ADC(R_1 + R_2) - 10230R_2}$$

$$R_t = \dfrac{R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]}{10230 R_1 - ADC(R_1 + R_2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Without having read your own reasoning in detail, I'll offer the following, which is less ad hoc, closer to a standard "classroom" approach.

$$ADC = (\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3} - \dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1}) \times 10 \times 1023$$

I'm going to go ahead and abbreviate $ADC$ by $a$, $\dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1}$ by $b$ and $10\cdot1023$ by $c$, so we can see more clearly the shape of the equation.

$$a = (\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3} - b)c=\dfrac{cR_t}{R_t + R_3}-bc$$

The key step that you're missing is to multiply both sides by $R_t + R_3$ so that your variable $R_t$ is no longer trapped under a fraction bar.

$$\begin{align}
a(R_t+R_3)&=cR_t-bc(R_t+R_3) \\
aR_t+aR_3&=cR_t-bcR_t-bcR_3 \\
(a+bc-c)R_t&=-aR_3-bcR_3
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You start off ok:

$(\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3}) = (\dfrac{ADC}{10230} + \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2})$ is correct.

$1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{ADC}{10230} + \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}}$ is a good idea because it gives you only one instance of $R_t$.

You can't  do what you tried to do next because $\frac 1 {a+b}$ is not equal to $\frac 1 a + \frac 1 b$ or $a+ b$.

$1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$ is the next line and I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks again for the help tomi, can you tell me if this is correct now?

Comment: Can someone let me know please, I just wanna be sure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can't cancel like that.

$1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$

$\dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}-\dfrac{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$

$\dfrac{R_3}{R_t}=\dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)-ADC(R_1+R_2)-10230R_2}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Thanks a lot tomi, I'll give it a go and post what i come up with.

Comment: How does that look to you tomi?

Comment: Excellent. You could simplify by getting rid of the two lots of $10230R_2$ In the denominator.

Comment: Great! Thanks tomi :]  Not really sure how to go about getting rid of the 10230R's lol. I don't know the rules well enough..

Answer (score 0):

$$R_t = \dfrac{R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]}{10230(R_1 + R_2) - ADC(R_1 + R_2) - 10230R_2}$$

$$R_t = \dfrac{R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]}{10230 R_1 +10230 R_2) - ADC(R_1 + R_2) - 10230R_2}$$

$$R_t = \dfrac{R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]}{10230 R_1 - ADC(R_1 + R_2)}$$

Comment: Brilliant tomi, I see it now!! haha.. Thanks very much for your time and help, I really appreciate it mate :D

Comment: Why did you leave several answers?

Comment: Sorry. New to this and probably making all kinds of errors.